# Any suggestions on how to ignore a file in a for loop after a Try/Catch Exception?

Tags: c#, json

I do want to ask for suggestions for this particular problem. Right now I have this custom file watcher that simply watches a folder and detects if there is any .json files and deserializes them. However, there is the possibility of it reading invalid ones and throwing out an exception. The problem I am facing is that because it is a service that is called repeatedly over 3 seconds, it will keep reading the invalid file and fill up the logs with the unsuccessful attempts to deserialize it.

I'm looking for suggestions to solve this issue and I hope to seek advice here.

The initial idea for me was to immediately do a File.Copy once the exception is caught and move it to another location so that it can't be watched by the service. But upon thinking about it, I figure it would be better if the service can recognize the invalid file and not perform the operation on said file while watching for others.

Here's a snippet of the code:

```
IENumerable<FileInfo> filesInDirectory = DirectoryInfo.GetFiles();

try {

    if(filesInDirectory.Any())
    {

        foreach(var file in filesInDirectory) 
        {

            if(file.Extension == ".json")
            {
                Logger("The file " + file.Name + " is being deserialized.");
                  //The file is read here for its contents and deserialized
            }

        }

        Logger("The file has been deserialized at " + DateTime.Now());

    }

catch 
{

//Exception handled here. Initially it was File.Copy and File.Delete(file.FullName);
}
```

The idea that I had was actually to put a boolean on the `var file` itself that flags it as read the moment the .json condition is fulfilled, and if it throws the exception it would be set to true that its read and be ignored. However, the I don't think I can tack on an attribute to the `FileInfo` class seeing that it is a System class.

If the deserialization is complete the file would be deleted from the directory, but if an invalid file remains in the directory; the `Logger` which is a custom function I wrote to log the service's actions by outputting messages to a text file, the log text file will show that it keeps recursively attempting to deserialize the invalid json file as long as it remains in the folder.

There is the possibility that a user might accidentally put a .json file in there that is not mapped to the `Foo` object and I don't want to touch the file, just skip it over.

It's something I thought of beyond the scope of my homework but I'm wondering if the idea is feasible or implementable, I would really love to see any suggestions or advice regarding this.

Comment: Well you could keep a list of file names that fail to deserialize and not try again if a file is in that list, but then if the file gets deleted and replaced, or even overwritten, your code won't try to read it again.

Comment: @CodeCaster Wow! It's actually a very feasible solution and simple too, in a way I could ask myself why didn't I think of that haha!

Comment: If the filed aren't very large I would keep a hash of the contents of your invalid files instead of the filename to avoid the issue mentioned by CodeCaster. This would allow you to reread and process files that were fixed with the same name.

Answer (score 2):

> The initial idea for me was to immediately do a File.Copy once the exception is caught and move it to another location so that it can't be watched by the service. But upon thinking about it, I figure it would be better if the service can recognize the invalid file and not perform the operation on said file while watching for others.

In message queue processing whether it be MSMQ; JMS; Apache; WebSphere; there is the concept of a message that after a certain number of failed retries if the item cannot be processed it is considered a **poison message** and moved to a **Poison Message Queue** for later investigations by Operations.

You can apply the same concept to file processing.  If after an attempt you cannot process it, either because it is a badly formed file; a file that reports that it is a JSON file but is in actual fact a JPEG of Miss Piggy incorrectly named as kermit.JSON; move it to a **Poison File** folder.

You **cannot assume** that just because something claims to be of a certain type that it is telling the truth.  In other words:

- Don't trust the file extension
- Don't trust the file size
- Don't assume you can open the file for reading (it could be encrypted by NTFS)
- Build in a rety facility.  Just because it fails the first time, does not mean it will fail the 2nd.  (maybe the file was just opened by something briefly like anti-virus)

Comment: Message queue processing? That sounds very fascinating, time to go read up on it and see if I can apply it practically. Thanks @MickyD!

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need to learn how to write defensive code, do the following:

1. check file extension ( == json)
2. check file size ( != 0)
3. validate schema agains needed shape with json tools ( I guess the code is .net so it will be [Json.net schema](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema) )

Write proper catch statements, not a catch all
Take a look at the documentation of the method you are using to parse, below is an example from `JsonDocument.Parse()`:

[image]
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsondocument.parse?view=netcore-3.0

So in this case you will have 3 catch statements

1. catch (JsonException je) { // handle here }
2. catch (ArgumentException ae) { // Handle here }
3. catch (Exception e) { // very unexpected error }

Comment: I'm relatively new to C# and defensive code sounds fascinating, also I'm trying to figure out how does catch exceptions work. What is the context of proper catch statements?

Comment: The method you use from the library will have documentation that shows what types of exception it might throw,

Comment: That's so cool! I'll take a look and implement it when I can! Thank you @Wandawi Najeeb R!